# What's the difference between using Cursor.Position, SetCursorPos(), SendInput() and mouse_event()?

Tags: c#, mouse-cursor

Cursor.Position, SetCursorPos(), SendInput() and mouse_event() all set the mouse position to a specified coordinate.

So what's the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [`Cursor.Position`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx) and [`SetCursorPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648394%28VS.85%29.aspx) can only be used to change the cursor position. `Cursor.Position` is Windows Forms; `SetCursorPos` is Win32.
- [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [`mouse_event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646260%28VS.85%29.aspx) can be used to change the cursor position as well as generate mouse clicks and mouse wheel events. `SendInput` is the current API; in addition to generating mouse events, it can also generate keyboard input. `mouse_event` is an earlier, deprecated API.

Comment: Do Cursor.Position and SetCursorPos use SendInput internally; or do they differ in implementation?

Comment: I have to admit I don't know, and I don't think this is documented anywhere. The closest you can get to an answer is probably to take a look at the implementation of SetCursorPos in Wine (www.winehq.com). If it uses SendInput, then that should be evidence that SetCursorPos is at least functionally equivalent to a subset of SendInput -- which is all that should matter.

Comment: @AshleySimpson SetCursor doesn't use SendInput internally. Disassemble win32u.dll and look for NtUserSetCursorPos and NtUserCallTwoParam. On windows 10 two separate syscalls are used.