# C# / Kinect Controlling the mouse cursor

Tags: c#, mouse, kinect

If I wanted to control the mouse cursor, including clicking etc, what API would I need to use for this?  For example, i'm developing an application for the PC using the Kinect, and I wish to control the mouse cursor with this, as opposed to creating my own in-app cursor.  What would I need to 'tap into' to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to simulate Mouse Click in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416748/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-in-c)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503238/whats-the-difference-between-using-cursor-position-setcursorpos-sendinput.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See answer from Marcos Placona in: [How to simulate Mouse Click in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416748/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-in-c/2416762#2416762)

Now you only need to add the mouse move events. More info here: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.mouse_event

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Form1 : Form
{
   [DllImport("user32.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
   public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);

   private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
   private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
   private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
   private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;

   public Form1()
   {
   }

   public void DoMouseClick()
   {
      //Call the imported function with the cursor's current position
      int X = Cursor.Position.X;
      int Y = Cursor.Position.Y;
      mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
   }

   //...other code needed for the application
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Will have a look at those links.